# Android dynamic forms

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying create a user input form which takes information about multiple users from a single form. Basically, each user data contains name, age, phone and email. The application user should be able to create n number of user data by clicking (+) button. When (+) is pressed same forms will be created again and app user can remove the user data by clicking (x) next each user entry.

How can this be done?

Comment: If you can show us some code and describe a problem you faced, it might help to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the model, such:

```
public class Entry {
     public String name, age, phone, email;
}
```

You will need two screens:

Main: a RecyclerView to hold the list and show the + button on screen and a x button on the item viewholder
Item: layout by xml the fields of the model (Entry) you want to fill

In Main, opens Item screen to fill a new Entry and return the new object to Main and add it to a List.